# How do I correctly let the browser update in the middle of a loop using setTimeout?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to use javascript to generate a sequence of images on a html5 canvas. Here's a fiddle of what I already have: http://jsfiddle.net/ws5e3rw6/1/

```
function loopColors(){
  for (r=0; r<1; r++){
      for (g=0; g<1; g++){
          for (b=0; b<256; b+=50){
              setTimeout(drawImage,1000,r,g,b);
          }
      }
  }
}
```

I've seen so many suggestions on this topic, and it's really frustrating, because none of them seem to be working for me. I've tried an anonymous function, like:

```
function loopColors(){
  for (r=0; r<1; r++){
      for (g=0; g<1; g++){
          for (b=0; b<256; b+=50){
              setTimeout(function(){drawImage(r,g,b);},1000);
          }
      }
  }
}
```

But that also doesnt work.

At the moment, after clicking the button, it waits for a second, then instantly jumps to the last blue color. I have no idea why.

I'm fairly new to javascript, so I may be missing something obvious.
Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: `setTimeout` is not `pause` or `wait`. It won't pause your script and wait 1 second before continuing the loop.

Comment: So you're saying that the loop continues and finishes before the drawImage function gets called? That would explain it. How would I go about achieving what I'm trying to do here, if setTimeout is the wrong way to do it?

Comment: There are two ways to go from here. You can change the time `1000*n` to the correct time, or you can execute the next `drawImage` only after the previous one has executed.

Comment: Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/ws5e3rw6/3/ This is done with a queue array, similar to how jQuery handles animations.

Answer (score 0):

Cheap solution would be to schedule callbacks every second instead all at once in a second.

Note that to make your code work reasonably you need to capture values of your loop variables, otherwise all callbacks will have the same value (if your code would actually pass values to your `drawImage` function).

```
function createCallback(r,g,b)
{
   return function(){drawImage(r,g,b);}; 
}

function loopColors(){
  var timeout = 10;
  for (r=0; r<1; r++){
    for (g=0; g<1; g++){
      for (b=0; b<256; b+=50){
          setTimeout(createCallback(r,g,b), timeout);
          timeout += 1000;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Proper fix would be to turn loops inside out to return next set of values every time (1,1,1), (1,1,2),... and have function it every second.